# parents remove doesn't work on appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to remove a div after it the remove link on that div is clicked.
The divs are generated using append after the website is loaded.

Appended HTML:

```
<div class="reviews">
<div class="row-fluid" id="57">
    <div class="span2">
        <img src="img/default_male.png" alt="Male Default Photo">
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
        <h6>Test Test</h6>
        <img class="rating-stars" src="img/2star.png" alt="2 Stars">
        <br>
        <p class="comment-info">
            <time class="timeago" datetime="2013-09-19 22:49:59" title="Thursday, Sep 19, 2013 - 10:49 PM">5 minutes ago</time>, 
            <a href="#removereview" class="removereview">remove</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JQuery Code:

```
            $(".reviews").on('click', '.removereview', function() {
            var review_id = $(this).parents('.row-fluid').attr('id');
            console.log(review_id);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "event_send.php",
                data: "func=remove_review&post_id=" + review_id + "&event_name=" + getUrlVars()["event_name"],
                success: function(response){
                    $(".review-count").html(parseInt($(".review-count").html()) - 1);
                    $(this).closest('.row-fluid').remove();
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

The problem is that the div doesn't get removed although the right ID is chosen by the code.
Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` inside the success handler does not refers the clicked element so your selector `$(this).closest('.row-fluid')` fails to find the element.

One solution is to use a closure variable `self` which then will be used inside the success handler

```
$(".reviews").on('click', '.removereview', function() {
    var review_id = $(this).parents('.row-fluid').attr('id');
    console.log(review_id);

    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "event_send.php",
        data: "func=remove_review&post_id=" + review_id + "&event_name=" + getUrlVars()["event_name"],
        success: function(response){
            $(".review-count").html(parseInt($(".review-count").html()) - 1);
            $(self).closest('.row-fluid').remove();
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Another is to use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass a custom context to the success callback

```
$(".reviews").on('click', '.removereview', function() {
    var review_id = $(this).parents('.row-fluid').attr('id');
    console.log(review_id);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "event_send.php",
        data: "func=remove_review&post_id=" + review_id + "&event_name=" + getUrlVars()["event_name"],
        success: $.proxy(function(response){
            $(".review-count").html(parseInt($(".review-count").html()) - 1);
            $(this).closest('.row-fluid').remove();
        }, this)
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks... the self one worked perfectly.
But why does self works and this doesn't, because they are pointing to the same thing. In other words, they are equal why one fails other doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to remove the element you got in `review_id`; Why not remove it directly?

```
$('#'+review_id).remove();
```

correct me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not going to work because the element has been generated using JQuery's append. In other words, when the page load up no link between the id and dom was made.